# Change value of element inside nested array, array created with Array().fill()

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Consider the code below. I want to change only the second elements value in the second list in `matrix`. The problem is, that somehow all elements are changed. How can this be?

```js
let matrix = Array(2).fill(Array(2).fill(0));
// [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
matrix[1][1] = 8
console.log(matrix)
// [[0, 8], [0, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because all elements inside `matrix` are pointing to or referencing the same list. By wanting to change one instance of the list, you change them all because you thereby change the list being pointed to. To avoid this, create an empty nested array using for-loops instead:

```js
let matr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  matr.push(Array(2).fill(0))
}
matr[1][1] = 8
console.log(matr)
```

Comment: No need to create a loop. `const matrix = Array.from({ length: 2 }, () => Array.from({ length: 2 }).fill(0));`.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianSimon